# Power settings on Windows 10 for WiFi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

Looks like my WiFi is falling a sleep after a certain time and it takes a long time for it to wake up. Is there a setting somewhere that would prevent my WiFi from falling a sleep?

I'm on a Surface Pro 4 with the latest Windows 10 updates, etc.  This really started happening ever since I installed the Fall Creators Update on my Surface. My current version of Windows 10 is 1709 and I'm completely up to date. I don't see any device issues in the device manager either.

My conclusion is that this has something to do with power settings but when I searched for it, I couldn't find a WiFi setting under power settings.

UPDATE:
I don't seem to have Power Management tab for the WiFi adapter in Device Manager.
[image]

Comment: "ever since I installed the Fall Creators Update" - sigh, perhaps try upgrading to Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7??? This is a Windows 10 update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-fall-creators-update

Comment: I know, I am sorry. I am being sarcastic. I am not a fan of this continues update thingy they are doing now.

Comment: I don't mind the continuous updates but Fall Creators Update has been a disaster for me and quite a few other Surface owners. Windows Hello stopped working, keyboard changes took us a few years back, WiFi issues, occasional blue screens of death. Not good!

Comment: Did you check under the Advanced tab? Due to it being an embedded Marvell radio, it's possible it may have different options, or options in different places, compared to a typical WiFi card.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. In Device Manager go to the Network Adapters and right click on the WiFi adapter.

In Properties select the Power Management tab and remove the check mark from the box Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power. Click OK to apply.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't seem to have Power Management tab for the WiFi adapter. I posted a screen shot on original post.

Comment: Power Management tab is not there.